# Move plugin made by builder into another project - October CMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-builder

I have created a plugin using builder and I want to move it to a new project.

Assuming this official thread : https://github.com/rainlab/builder-plugin/issues/113 , It should be done by copying the plugin located in `/plugins` into the new `/plugins` project folder. But the plugin doesn't appear in the builder.

I also tried to referesh the two plugins :

```
artisan plugin:refresh RainLab.Builder
artisan plugin:refresh Leme.Products    //the plugin that I created
```

Need some help.

Comment: just copy and paste is enough, but if the plugin has data in the database then you need to manually move them. if you share with us info about what error you are facing may be we can assist you

Comment: @HardikSatasiya The plugin doesn't appear in the builder

Answer (score 1):

Make the command

```
artisan october:up
```

Then make the commands

```
php artisan plugin: enable RainLab.Builder
php artisan plugin: enable Leme.Products
```

If that doesn't work, then you need to check the local plugin paths. Should be:

```
~/plugins/rainLab/builder
~/plugins/leme/products
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a new plugin with the same author name and now I can see the plugin that I copied appear in the builder with the new one.
Maybe something with the cache..